# Outlier removal via cooks distance and lm models

Tags: r, outliers

I try to program a way to remove outliers from a linear model. I want to be more flexible about the formulas I use for this purpose. But it does not work.

```
require(caret)
random_samples <- createDataPartition(iris$Sepal.Length, times=10, p=0.8)

getTrainTest <- function(Index, data){
  train_data <- data[Index, ] # test_data = Umfang von test_rowLocations --> Datensatz k
  test_data <- data[-Index, ] # training data = OG data frame - test data
  return(list("train"=train_data, "test"=test_data))
}

datasets <- lapply(random_samples, getTrainTest, iris)

forumla1 <- as.formula(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length)

compute_cooks_models <- function(x,eq){
  cooks.distance(lm(eq, 
                    data = x, na.action = na.exclude))}

result <- Map (compute_cooks_models,datasets, eq=forumla1)
```

Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

I don't get what I am doing wrong??

Could some one help me out?
Nadine

Comment: I added the tag R to your question. I would advise you to find the questions you want answered, and which are still haven't been, and go through the tags you used on them. People who are likely to help might not see it at all if you don't use the right tag. Most important tag to add is the programming language you're using

Comment: My answer to your question might be a bit late. But I thought it might help someone else if you've already solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues there in your code.

- `datasets` is a list of lists of dataframes, so when you loop through them with `Map` you are looping through the first level, thus passing in a list to the function `compute_cooks_models`. If you'd like to train the `lm` model with the training set then you have to use `x$train` in the argument data
- The second issue is with the use of `Map` this function assumes that you're passing a vector or a list of values for each argument in the function. An example can be the following:

```
my_fun <- function(x, y){
  paste0(x, y)
}

Map(my_fun, letters[1:5], 1:5)

## Output:
# $a
# [1] "a1"
# 
# $b
# [1] "b2"
# 
# $c
# [1] "c3"
# 
# $d
# [1] "d4"
# 
# $e
# [1] "e5"
```

This means in your case that the function is trying to get the first
element from `datasets` and the first element from `forumla1`, which will of course cause an error when passing one symbol of the formula to the `lm` call.
You could instead use `sapply` which will do wht you need I think, like so:

```
forumla1 <- as.formula(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length)

compute_cooks_models <- function(x,eq){
  cooks.distance(lm(eq, data = x$train, na.action = na.exclude))
  }

result <- sapply(datasets, compute_cooks_models, eq=forumla1)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much - I'll check it out!